# Tag dispatching, variadic template, universal reference and the missed const specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, variadic-templates

Please, consider the following example (tag dispatching, variadic template, perfect forwarding, and so on, all in one):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

struct A { };
struct B { };

void doIt(A&&, const std::string &) {
    std::cout << "A-spec" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void doIt(T&&, Args&&...) {
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fn(Args&&... args) {
    doIt(T{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    const std::string foo = "foo";
    std::string bar = "bar";
    fn<A>(foo);
    fn<A>(bar);
    fn<B>(foo);
}
```

In that case, the output is:

```
A-spec
template
template
```

The reason is quite obvious, it doesn't bother me.

What I'd like to achieve is to call the first instance of the `doIt` function in both the cases, no matter if the string has the const specifier or not.
Of course, a possible solution is to define a new `doIt` with the right prototype, anyway I'd like to know if there is also another solution.

So far, I've tried to get it by means of `add_const`, but I'm quite sure I missed something.
Is there any viable solution to add silently the const specifier and get it working?

**EDIT**

I've updated the example above, in order to be more coherent with the real problem.
Moreover, despite the interesting answers, I forgot to cite that this is only a reduced example, so the real problem does not involve only `std::string`. Instead, it could happen that (as an example) for tag `A` the arguments are `int` and `const std::string &`, while for tag `B` the arguments are `float`, instance of class `C`, and so on.
Because of that, those answers that try to solve the problem using somehow the `std::string` type won't solve the real problem, I'm sorry.

Comment: I take it that the template version of `doIt` should still use perfect forwarding after the change?

Comment: @skypjack is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4beb48345f47162) what you need ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki only if you'll put everything in a more detailed answer, for I'm still trying to figure out why it works!! :-) ... Anyway, it seems what I'm looking for indeed.

Comment: Saying "the situation is more complex" does not help, nor listing types that coukd be arguments.  Please be more specific: actual code that does not work, and which making work would help.  Your output no longer matches your example either.

Comment: @Yakk Updated the response about one hours ago (added what you are asking for, that is examples of types), fixed the output right now (thank you for have noticed it). Because the types of `Args` can be all the ones available, I guess the current available code is enough. Simply, do not try to base your solution on the string type, as I said. To downvote because you misunderstood the question is quite useless, anyway... as you prefer, I won't toggle my vote on your response for it is still interesting. ;-)

Comment: I'm judging the question as being poorly written.  It still contains the **Edit** section -- fix problems, don't add appendixes.  It says what not to do, but not *what to you want it to do* specifically.  When someone has to guess what your problem is before they can answer, the question needs work.  You have an answer, but the question *as written* won't be helpful for other people, hence the down vote.

Comment: @Yakk I cannot agree with you, but I suggest and invite you to flag the question if this is your opinion. I want to remove from SO questions that are useless, so if mine is one of them it is right to drop it, absolutely. Otherwise, the downvote appears as a consequence of a misunderstanding and this doesn't reflect your reputation at all.

Comment: I have listed explicit ways to improve your question, and explicit problems with it.  Feel free to ping me back if/when you have fixed the question, if you care.  Otherwise, have a good day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce two separate functions, so that they won't collide with each other and the compiler won't raise any ambiguity error:

```
void doIt(A&&, const std::string &)
{
    std::cout << "A-spec" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void doIt_template(T&&, Args&&...)
{
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}
```

Prioritize two additional overloads; the preferred one is that which tries to call a specialized, non-templated version of a target function:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto fn_impl(int, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(doIt(T{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
{
    doIt(T{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void fn_impl(char, Args&&... args)
{
    doIt_template(T{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Introduce a single, general dispatcher:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void fn(Args&&... args)
{
    fn_impl<T>(0, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4beb48345f47162)

Comment: Am I wrong or `decltype` is used to force `SFINAE` during resolution, so that the first implementation of `fn_impl` gives an error for those tags that are not specialized?

Comment: @skypjack yes, that's an expression SFINAE, and it's forced to be checked in the first place, since it takes `int` as its first parameter, which exact-matches `0` in `fn_impl<T>(0, ...`

Comment: Got it, thank you, that's what I was looking for. Congratulations, really a good answer.

Comment: It's not fully clear to me why the `void()` as part of the expression for the `decltype`, was not enough the first part? (sorry if I bother you, but I'd like to fully understand it!!)

Comment: @skypjack if `doIt` returns `void` as well then yes, it's redundant

Comment: Ok, I suspected it, but wanted to be reassured. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Overloading on forwarding references is a pain, as they are very, very greedy.

One option would be to disable the template version if `Args...` is a single argument convertible to `std::string`:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct convertible_to_single_string {
    static std::true_type help (std::string);
    static std::false_type help (...);
    using type = decltype(help(std::declval<Args>()...));
    static constexpr auto value = type::value;
};

template<typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!convertible_to_single_string<Args...>::value, void> 
doIt(int, Args&&...) {
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}
```

This would also call the string version for `const char*` or anything with a user-defined conversion to `std::string`. If you don't want that, there are other possibilities, like removing all references and cv-qualifiers from the type and checking if it `std::is_same<std::string, T>`.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9f664f304f81191)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the real problem is more complex than a simple argument of type `std::string`. Please, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class String,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<String>,std::string>{},int> =0
>
void doIt(int, String&&) {
  std::cout << "std::string" << std::endl;
}
```

This uses a forwarding reference, then SFINAE to get any `string` types only in it.

If you are willing to bundle your args into a tuple, you can also do this usimg tag dispatching.  `is_same` can be replaced with `is_convertible`, then a helper function with a different name that actually converts to `std::string` can be used.

Another approach would be to reserve the first arg in the 2nd layer for tags, then manually work out what overload you want, and generate that tag type.

Comment: Regarding the last solution, isn't it ambiguous? const-qualification vs. a user-defined conversion?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the real problem is more complex than a simple argument of type `std::string`. Please, see the updated question.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Hurm, you are right: for some odd reason I thought constness conversion was on a different tier than user-defined conversion.  I was wrong.